# C#: Best way to implement a named pipe intermediary

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement a named pipe reader/writer in the most efficient way possible. In short, Powershell uses Powershell Remoting Protocol (XML + Binary) via a named pipe to communicate with a debug host. I want to make this process remote, so to accomplish that I want to:

1. Set up the following streaming chain: NamedPipeServerStream <-> TCP Stream <-> NamedPipeServerStream (on another computer) where a client will then connect to the remote namedpipeserverstream. For these purposes just connecting to the named pipe remotely via SMB isn't sufficient, it needs to be encapsulated in a single TCP connection
2. All I want my client/server daemon to do is listen for data from one side and pass it to the other, so I can connect a powershell debug process from a remote system.
3. Once I get this working I'll replace the TCP stream with a rendevous service like ngrok or Azure Relay Hybrid COnnection, so that I can start a debug process and then remotely debug it anywhere.

Basically I want to recreate socat in c#. What's the best nonblocking way to do this? Tasks? System.IO.Pipeline?